# Serial port communication in C

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm just start writing an app to control SimCOM by serial port. But i have trouble to receive data from serial port. This is my program.

```
/*Sending command*/
    char cmd[80] = "ATD";
    char number[80];
    printf("Calling: \n");
    printf("Input your phone number:");
    scanf("%s",number);
    char signal[80]= ";\r\n";
    strcat(cmd,number);
    strcat(cmd,signal);
    printf("%s",cmd);
    int nWritten = write(fd, &cmd,sizeof(cmd));
```

I can't read data correctly. otherwise sending data is okay with same baud rate 
    /*Read data response*/

```
    int n = 0;
    char buf[1];
    char response[256];

    do
    {
     n = read(fd, &buf, 1 );
     strcat(response,buf);
    }
    while( buf[1] != '\r' && n > 0);


    printf("%s \n", response);
```

This is my open part of my program

```
struct termios options;

    int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd==-1){
        printf("Cannot open serial port\n");
    }
    else printf("Serial port: open.\n");


    /*config serial port*/
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);

    cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);


    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; //no parity
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; //one stop bit
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; // size
    options.c_cflag &= CS8; // 8 bit
```

Comment: In data communication you end write with `EOT`. In ascii it's `char(4)`. When reading, you read until you get `EOT` `(char 4)`.

Comment: one logical error: `while( buf[1] != '\r' && n > 0);` should be `while( buf[0] != '\r' && n > 0);`

Comment: @alvits -- You're describing an atypical serial protocol.  A canonical serial link for transferring ASCII text would likely use newline or carriage return characters.  That's what the POSIX default *line discipline* uses.

Comment: *"otherwise sending data is okay"* -- Actually you don't know if the sent data is received by the modem. You only know that **write()** didn't kill your program. It may return an error that's not checked. Your open and initialization code is incomplete. The return from **tc[gs]etattr()** should be checked. What does *"I can't read data correctly"* mean?  Your read code is flawed.  Assuming a canonical read, your code would only repeatedly get the *first* byte of each *line* (since the requested length is "1").  Also you use the address of an array address in both **write()** and **read()**.

Comment: Thank you. I add some initialization code. And it work.:D

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the open() part of your program. You can not simply read from the serial port using read() without setting the baud rate and other parameters. [Here is](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html) a good example from The Linux Documentation project which might be helpful

Comment: This "answer" does not offer a solution to the problem, and is really just a comment.  Also the provided link is not that good; it doesn't follow POSIX practices as described in [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) and

[Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).